# account expiration/password expiration in active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I work in a tech office and a lot of my job is to reset passwords/ change expiration dates on active directory accounts. Since I do not have access to the actual server, just my administrative tools -> active directory users and computers is what I have.

Every week or so I am given a list of usernames, I am to check and see if their passwords are expired, and if their account is expired. If the account is expired I have a date I need to set it to, if the p/w is expired each user has a predetermined p/w

I have been reading here around SA and powershell.com trying to figure out a way to write a script to check each of these accounts in my file and set each account as needed; however I can't seem to get information on the accounts.

I have tried `Get-LDAPUser` , I have tried using `Get-ADUser -Filter` and`Get-ADUser username -acctExpires`.I keep getting a no cmdlet errors here,  Also tried to see if I could somehow just access partial information using the `Net User *user* /domain to no avail

I am not asking for an answer as I know I have shown no work, but if this can be done I would like a step in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function FileTime2Date($time) {
  return ([datetime]::FromFileTime($time)).DateTime
}

$today = Get-Date
$userlist = Get-Content "C:\path\to\username.list"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |
  select sAMAccountName, accountExpirationDate, @{n='passwordExpiry';
    e={FileTime2Date $_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed'}} |
  ? { $userlist -contains $_.sAMAccountName -and (
      $_.accountExpirationDate -le $today -or
      $_.passwordExpiry -le $today
    )
  }
```

Untested, though, since I don't have an AD at hand right now.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
# Check if the users account is expired
FUNCTION IsExpired ($Name)
{
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ExpirationDate=(Get-ADUser $Name -Properties 'AccountExpirationDate').AccountExpirationDate
$Result = ($ExpirationDate -lt (Get-Date))
Return $Result
}
```